# Android load multiple firestore documents

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a spinner. Into that spinner I added one of my firestore collections. I thought but calling the collection I could load any data into my spinner, but when I added a second document to my collection it stopped working.

This is what I have right now:

```
db.collection("KitList").get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        for (document in snapshot.documents) {
            val data = document.data
            val skipRope = data["rope"] as String
            spinnerArray.add(skipRope)
            val kettle = data["kettle"] as ArrayList<String>
            for (item in kettle) {
                val kettleWeight = "kettle $item"
                spinnerArray.add(kettleWeight)
            }

        }

    }
```

I tried `db.collection("KitList").document("documentname")get().addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->` but it didn't work because my snapshot.documents got an error.

Could anyone help me out here? Just want to know how I can can call multiple documents. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

1st, create your custom data model (I will call it DataClass).
Then, in addOnSuccessListener put this code:

```
snapshot.documents.mapTo(spinnerArray) { it.toObject(DataClass::class.java)}
```

Of course, replace DataClass with your own :)